# Is there a command to make another command or process complete faster?

Tags: process, time

#### Background

I was using `sudo renice -20 -p <pid>` thinking it would make my videos convert faster.

On testing the time it had no effect and then I found out that speed has nothing to do with niceness.

#### Question

Is there a command that allows a process or command to complete faster, perhaps by limiting other processes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a cmd to make another cmd or process complete faster?

Yes, there is.

And you found it: `nice` / `renice`
will adjust the scheduler priority.

Now, will it *always* have an effect? No.
It's only relevant when competing processes,
maybe a background `gzip`,
are hogging CPU cycles and preventing
your video conversion from being scheduled.

If your system was otherwise idle when
you converted a video, then no amount of
adjusting scheduler priorities will make
a difference to elapsed time.
You *already* have the whole machine
devoted to this task, so changing a priority
figure won't alter the scheduling.

Change a CPU overclock setting,
or buy a faster CPU.
Verify that processor cooling is effective.

Comment: as I see so that's when nice comes in handy. Any cmd to overclock the cpu? Seems you have to edit bios use guis for that

Comment: The trouble with overclocking is there's a decent chance of permanently damaging your equipment. Anyone in the overclocking community would caution you to keep a close eye on observed temperature and shut down at once if it gets out of hand. It's not a quick fix kind of thing, it deserves serious study. There's a reason your system is designed to run at the speed it's set to. If you're looking for something that's easy, better to look at AWS and its competitors than at overclocking. Some cloud servers offers speeds much greater than 3 GHz.